# Can't use the "use client", it broke my fetch with next.JS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am a beginner in React and Next.JS, I am currently trying some small project to get used to Next.JS 13 and I tried just getting data from the API : https://www.dnd5eapi.co/ .

I first fetch some data inside my `page.js` in the `/app` directory. So far no problem. Then I created a `[classe]` folder with a `page.jsx` inside of it. I received the data with `params` and I can easily display some data using this code :

```
export default async function ClassesDetail({ params }) {
  const { classe } = params;
  const data = await fetch(`https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/classes/${classe}`);
  const res = await data.json();

  const skills = res.proficiency_choices[0].from.options.map((skill) => ({
    name: skill.item.name.slice(6),
    index: skill.item.index.slice(6),
  }));

  const skillsData = await Promise.all(
    skills.map(async (skills) => {
      const data = await fetch(
        `https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/skills/${skills.index}`
      );
      const res = await data.json();
      return res;
    })
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{res.name}</h1>
        <h2>
          Proficiencies : {res.proficiency_choices[0].desc}
        </h2>
        <div>
          {skillsData.map((skill) => {
            const matchedSkill = skills.find((s) => s.index === skill.index);
            return (
              <div key={skill.index}>
                <h3>{matchedSkill.name}</h3>
                <p>{skill.desc}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link href="./">
          Back Home
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

But I wanted to put a `onClick` on the `{skill.desc}` for example but once I try to use the `"use client"` I received an error

```
const skills = res.proficiency_choices[0].from.options.map((skill) => ({
     |                                ^
  11 |       name: skill.item.name.slice(6),
  12 |       index: skill.item.index.slice(6),
  13 |     }));
```

and this :

```
error - Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

And to be honest I don't know why. Can someone explain me what is this error and why just changing to client make this error appears.

Thanks in advance.
Have a great day.

I tried to create a client component inside a folder call `component` and I also tried to create a async function inside my `export default function ClassesDetail()` but the error was the same.

Comment: For fetching data in client components you still need to use an async function inside useEffect

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I realized that the async component and "use client" at the same time makes an infinite loop, so I removed async and changed my code